# Twilio Forwarding the "Calling Number"

Tags: twilio, forwarding

Twilio Newbie with QOTD (Question of the Day).  I figure this should be pretty basic but I cannot seem to find the answer.

I was successful in forwarding a phone number to my cell phone....Easy....But the problem is that I run a couple of businesses that I would like to forward the number to my cell phone.  The problem is that when the call comes in it is shown as the number that is calling.  I am looking for it to pass to the cell phone the number that was called.

For Example:

My cell number is 111-111-1111.   I have 3 Twilio Numbers for 3 businesses (222-222-2222; 333-333-3333; and 444-444-4444).  I receive a phone call to my Twilio number of 222-222-2222.  The Person A that is calling is calling from 999-999-9999.

With my current forward when Person A is calling it shows his number on my cell's caller id of 999-999-9999.  The problem is that I do not know the number to be for what business and how to answer.  I would like to answer Hello this is Mike with Business A can I help you.

How do I get it to pass the right Twilio number so when Person A calls 222-222-2222 my caller ID on my cell phone shows 222-222-2222 instead of the caller's number.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: You need to share some code.

Answer (score 9):

Twilio employee here.

This is pretty easy to do with some [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) manipulation. Just set the [callerId](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id) attribute to the number you want to see on your phone, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial callerId="222-222-2222">
    <Number>111-111-1111</Number>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

If you need any more help, let me know!

Comment: This is not what's been asked. I think he wants to forward the callerID of the person calling, not his own number.

Comment: The posted answer is correct. The callerId of the person calling is the default behavior and this lets you set the callerId to be any number you want.